# How can I set plt to automatically use the 'classic' style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use `plt.style.use('classic')` for all the plotting later. Is there anyway to define `plt.style.use('classic')` as `plt`. So later, each time when I use `plt`, it automatically plot it in classic style.

I tried import `matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('classic') as plt`
It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with this:

```
import matplotlib.style

matplotlib.style.use('classic')
```

Setting the style this way should make it so any plots you create will use the `'classic'` stylesheet.

FWIW `matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('classic') as plt` is invalid syntax. If you really wanted to do something like this, you'd use variable assignment e.g.:

```
plt = matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('classic')
```

...but `matplotlib.pyplot.style.use()` returns `None` so this is fairly useless and should only be taken as an example

Comment: If you read again OP's question, you may realize that they know the correct usage of `plt.style.use('classic')`, otoh they want to AVOID using it, probably using some sort of dot file. Is it possible that the whole of your answer is quite unnecessary?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I must say, I'm used to *some* level of condescension on StackOverflow, but this is impressive. Perhaps in the future you could seek to provide helpful constructive criticism without resorting to imperiousness. Please feel free to provide an alternative answer if you're so inclined.

Comment: ① I won't post an answer here because I don't know the answer.  ② Not knowing the correct answer doesn't mean that I cannot spot an unnecessary one. ③ Is this comment on par with my previous level of condescension? ;-) — I'm sorry to have impressed you, my excuse is, I'm not mother tongue so I miss some nuances (also, I tend to be a bit condescending even when I communicate in Italian, but then I have a better knowledge of the context). My apologies and goodbye.